# Find the closed form of a summation from $k=1$ to $n$

Tags: calculus, summation, closed-form

For my discrete mathematics class, I need to express this summation in closed form in terms of $n$,

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(6 + 2 \cdot \frac{k}{n}\right)^2. $$

I was in the hospital when they went over this in class, and they were not working out of the textbook. I've looked extensively online and found plenty of cases where people solved problems like this, but no one explained how they did it.

I know the first thing to do is to multiply out the expression, but I'm not sure how to proceed from there. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

---

Based on the responses you all have given me, I have an idea of how I should solve this. Can anyone verify that this is correct?

so:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(6 + 2 \cdot \frac{k}{n}\right)^2 $$

$$\equiv \sum_{k=1}^n 36 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{24k}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{4k^2}{n^2}$$

$$\equiv 36 + \frac{24}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n k + \frac{4}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$

$$\equiv 36 + \frac{24}{n} \cdot \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} + \frac{4}{n^2} \cdot\frac{n(n + 1)(2n + 1)}{6}$$

..and then simplify? Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the summation formulas for $\sum k$ and $\sum k^2$?

Comment: When you sum 36, it should be 36n, as you are summing the number 36 n times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some formulas you need to memorize if you want to do this without a reference.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k}=\frac{n(n+1)}2$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n{k^2}=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$
Using these formulas together with basic algebraic manipulation will get you the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still not entirely sure how to proceed. When I multiply out the expression I get the sum_(k=1)^{n} (36 + 24k/n + k^2/n^2). Can I just substitute that whole k^2 equality that you shared in for the k^2 in the multiplied out expression and get rid of the summation, and then simplify?

Comment: @Baba I guess you'll also have to memorize $\sum(a+b)=\sum a +\sum b$, and you can factor out expressions that do not depend on the index of summation (which is $k$ in this case).

Comment: that was the missing piece!! Thank you! I haven't taken calculus in years and I forgot you could do that.

Comment: @Baba No problem. Be sure to upvote any answers you find helpful, and you can also accept answers if you feel they've resolved your problem. On other SE sites there's some kind of ritual waiting period for accepting answers, but I'm unsure what it is because it's not often observed here.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it.

$(6 + 2\frac kn)^2 = 36 + \frac 24n k + \frac 4{n^2}k^2$

So $\sum_{k=1}^n (6 + 2\frac kn)^2=\sum_{k=1}^n(36 + \frac 24n k + \frac 4{n^2}k^2)=$

$\sum_{k=1}^n 36 + \frac 24n\sum_{k=1}^n k + \frac4{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=$

$36n + \frac 24n\frac {n(n+1)}2 +  \frac 4{n^2}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6=$

$36n +12(n+1) +\frac 2{3n}(n+1)(2n+1)=$

$\frac {144n^2 + 12n +2(n^2+ 3n+1)}{3n}=$

$\frac {146n^2 + 18n + 2}{3n}$

Comment: Thank you so much for writing all of this out. Shouldn't your first line say (24\n)*k instead of 6 though? Or am I doing that wrong?

Comment: @BabaSvoloch. You are correct : the $6$ should be $24$.

Comment: Somehow I thought the two was in a denominator.